# Need ia32-libs to run 32bit app on 64 bit OS

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, emulation

I need to use the program topdrawer.
There is only a 32 bit version of topdrawer available, so according to their wiki I need to install ia32-libs to use it. However, when I try

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I get the following error message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried to install ia32-libs-multiarch as well, but I get:

```
E: Package 'ia32-libs-multiarch' has no installation candidate
```

Please bear in mind I am quite new to linux - I only installed it a few months ago so that I could use Madgraph, which is what I now need topdrawer for.

Answer (score 1):

The app is the same with skype i think. So the workaround is to install first your app(topdrawer), better if its .deb file. It will not run after installation. You need to run `sudo apt-get install -f` and let apt-get automatically detect and install the dependencies. This procedure is based on installation of skype on my system that also requires ia32-libs.